# spring-data-jpa Error creating bean with name

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm a novice developer. Not long ago I started studying `'jpa'`.
and I created a spring project with java config.

My project spec:

- `Java : 1.8`
- `servlet : 3.1`
- `spring : 4.3.2.RELEASE`
- `tomcat : 8.5`
- `spring-data-jpa 2.0.0.RELEASE`
- `hibernate 5.1.0.Final`

**My code:**

**ServletConfig.class**

```
@Configuration                                      
@EnableWebMvc                                       
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.knk.spring4")    
public class ServletConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
........
}
```

**PersistenceConfig.class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.knk.spring4.repository") 
public class PersistenceConfig {
.....
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public EntityManagerFactory entityMangerFactory() {

        logger.info("EntityMangerFactory");

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emf.setPersistenceUnitName("springDataTest");
        emf.setDataSource(getDataSource()); 
        emf.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"com.knk.spring4.entity"}); 

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        emf.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        emf.afterPropertiesSet();

        return emf.getObject();
    }
.......
}
```

**MemberEntity.class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MEMBER_KNK")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "MEMBERIDX_SEQ_GENERATOR"
                    , sequenceName = "MEMBERIDX_SEQ"
                    , initialValue = 1)
public class MemberEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE
                    , generator = "MEMBERIDX_SEQ_GENERATOR")
    private long memberIdx;
........
}
```

**MemberRepository.class**

```
@Repository
public interface MemberRepository extends JpaRepository<MemberEntity, Long> {

    @Query("select m from MemberVO m where m.id=:id")
    public MemberEntity getMemberIDbyId(@Param("id") String id);
}
```

**MemberService.class**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class MemberService {

    @Autowired 
    private MemberRepository memberRepository;
........
}
```

**The error I'm getting:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'memberController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'memberService': Error creating bean with name 'memberService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'memberRepository': Error creating bean with name 'memberRepository': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'memberRepository': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'memberService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'memberRepository': Error creating bean with name 'memberRepository': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'memberRepository': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:540)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:992)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4931)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5241)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'memberService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'memberRepository': Error creating bean with name 'memberRepository': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'memberRepository': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'memberRepository': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:99)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    ... 52 more
```

I think that's the problem.

`ServletConfig.class` or `PersistenceConfig.class` pakagescan

so i did

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.knk.spring4.controller", "com.knk.spring4.repository", "com.knk.spring4.service"})
```

and

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.knk.spring4"})

@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.knk.spring4.repository")
```

I've tried everything ' * ' and ' ** ' on the Basepackages path.

Comment: I believe this has something to do with your jar versions. try changing version of servlet, or spring-jpa ....

Comment: Spring Data JPA 2 requires Spring 5.

Comment: try to change in query ..this will solve your problem

Comment: `public MemberEntity getMemberIDbyId(@Param("id") Long id);`   ..because your entity class id is `long` type ..

Comment: Thanks for the answer, everyone, thanks to you! The problem was a version of 'spring-data-jpa'. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try replacing @Query("select m from MemberVO m where m.id=:id") with
@Query("select m from MemberEntity m where m.memberIdx=:id")

Comment: That won't solve "java.lang.AbstractMethodError" in Spring classes

Comment: The error is with creating the repository, so it might be that something is wrong with that, and the query seems incompatible with the names of the entity class, so it might not be the only issue, but I don't see how that query would work.

Comment: @BillyFrost.. look the exception `java.lang.AbstractMethodError` and this Thrown when an application tries to call an abstract method. Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of some class has incompatibly changed since the currently executing method was last compiled.

Comment: and `MemberRepository` is interface and  it content abstract method of course `getMemberIDbyId` is abstract method.

Comment: i think this explanation is ok for you ..and this not classpath problem ..i had also face same issue ..

Comment: Thanks for the answer, everyone, thanks to you! The problem was a version of 'spring-data-jpa'. Thanks again.